# Curve defined by reducible polynomial is the union of curves of its irreducible factors.

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-curves

My book said it is easy to see this:
"If a polynomial $P$ is the product of two factors $P =P_1 .P_2$, then, $C_P$, the curve defined by $P$, is equal to $C_{P_1} \cup C_{P_2}$, where $C_{P_i}$ is the curve defined by $P_i, i =1,2$".

But I'm not sure of this. For example, $x^3 = x^2 . x$, but the graph of $x^3$ isn't the union of a line and a parabola...

Comment: The curve $C_P$ is *not* the graph of $P$. Rather, it is the set of points satisfying $P=0$. So for $x^3$, its zero set is $x=0$; the same is true for both $x^2$ and $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at the zero set of $0=P$. For example if $P=x^2-y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$, then the curve defined by $P$ is the union of the two lines $0=x+y$ and $0=x-y$.

Comment: But how it is in the case of $x^2$? The zero set of $x^2=0$ would be $x $ and $ x$ and the curve will be the two lines $x=0$ and $x=0$?

Comment: Yes that's right.